# Using python mss to draw bounding box on top of screen record

Tags: python, opencv, python-mss

I have code to screen record and with each frame I have a set of bounding boxes I want to display on each frame. I can do this using `matplotlib` or something but I `mss` is working at like 30fps and I need to be able to display the bounding boxes quickly.

I noticed in docs [this example](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html#playing-with-pixels) but I tried running it and can't get it to display anything. And I'm not even sure this would work with my example.

```py
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
from mss import mss

with mss() as sct:
        # Part of the screen to capture
        monitor = {"top": 79, "left": 265, "width": 905, "height": 586}

        while "Screen capturing":
            last_time = time.time()

            # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
            screen = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))

            # print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

            print('loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
            last_time = time.time()
            screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            screen = cv2.resize(screen, (224,224)).astype(np.float32)/255

            # Display the picture
            cv2.imshow("OpenCV/Numpy normal", screen)

            # Press "q" to quit
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```

Now say I have a set of bounding boxes to display on each frame, for example,

```
bboxes = [np.array([12, 16, 29, 25]), np.array([5,  5, 38, 35])]
```

Can I alter the pixels in some way to display this. I suppose I could do it via `opencv` as well since that is what is displaying the screen ultimately.

EDIT: In reference to the comment about the bounding boxes, they are `x1, y1, width, height`, and are in the resized `(224,224)` image

Comment: I updated with a "full-code" in case you need it. I didn't know `mss`. Thanks for introducing it to me :)

Comment: @Berriel Awesome, it worked perfectly. Yes `mss` is great, it took my screen grabs to 20x faster than `PIL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some missing details:

- What is the format of the bounding boxes: `[x1, y1, x2, y2]` or `[x1, y1, width, height]` or something else?
- Are the bounding boxes values in the resized (`224, 224`) or original range?

Anyway, you can use the function below to draw the rectangles (you need to choose based on the format):

```py
def draw_bboxes(img, bboxes, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=1):
    for bbox in bboxes:
        # if [x1, y1, x2, y2]
        cv2.rectangle(img, tuple(bbox[:2]), tuple(bbox[-2:]), color, thickness)
        # if [x1, y1, width, height]
        cv2.rectangle(img, tuple(bbox[:2]), tuple(bbox[:2]+bbox[-2:]), color, thickness)
```

Assuming you defined your `bboxes`, you can call the function:

- If you want to draw on the original frame:

```py
# [...]
screen = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
draw_bboxes(screen, bboxes)
# [...]
```

- If you to draw on the resized frame:

```py
# [...]
screen = cv2.resize(screen, (224,224)).astype(np.float32)/255
draw_bboxes(screen, bboxes)
# [...]
```

With some changes, the full-code would look like this:

```py
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
from mss import mss

def draw_bboxes(img, bboxes, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=1):
    for bbox in bboxes:
        cv2.rectangle(img, tuple(bbox[:2]), tuple(bbox[:2]+bbox[-2:]), color, thickness)

# bounding boxes
bboxes = [np.array([12, 16, 29, 25]), np.array([5,  5, 38, 35])]

with mss() as sct:
    # part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 79, "left": 265, "width": 905, "height": 586}
    while "Screen capturing":
        # get screen
        last_time = time.time()
        screen = np.asarray(sct.grab(monitor))
        print('loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))

        # convert from BGRA --> BGR
        screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
        # resize and draw bboxes
        screen = cv2.resize(screen, (224,224))
        draw_bboxes(screen, bboxes)

        # display
        cv2.imshow("OpenCV/Numpy normal", screen)

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

The output would be something like this:

[image]